# Accessing grouped UITableView section view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Basically I want to "cut the corners" of the first cell imageview and the last cell imageview to match the curved corners on the grouped tableview section.

I was given the advice to do this by setting the view's masksToBounds property to true?

Anyone know how to access this view? Doing cell.superview doesn't work. cell.contentView.superview doesn't work and cell.backgroundView.superview doesn't work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no section view.  A cell's superview is the UITableView itself.

The rounded corner drawing is done by UITableViewCell's backgroundView, and backgroundView isn't in imageView's view hierarchy (contentView and backgroundView are siblings—their superview is the Cell itself), so unfortunately masksToBounds won't work.

Comment: and idea how to achieve this then? In the itunes app the album pictures have a curved top left corner in the top-most cell of the grouped tableview. How would you do this?

Comment: accepted as is an answer to my question. I've since found a method to do this.

Comment: I've always just masked the images programatically. Did you find a better way?